# how can I determine the Field of View a street view panorama map is using

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I notice the Field of View (FOV) degree per street view zoom level is different between browsers

I believe the documented street view zoom level to FOV is

```
0: 180, 1: 90, 2: 45, 3: 22.5, 4: 11:25
```

I am using the v3 Maps API with street view panorama and get zoom levels to FOV in chrome around

```
0: 127, 1: 90, 2: 53, 3: 28, 4: 14
```

These zoom to FOV are the same in IE7 and IE8

in Firefox and IE6 they are:

```
0: 180, 1: 90, 2: 45, 3: 22.5, 4: 11:25
```

- Is this documented?
- How can I enforce the street view FOV
  consistently across browsers or calculate the FOV value for that zoom
  level?

Comment: Checking the Maps API will probably be a good way to answer the first question. Did you try doing this?

Comment: thanks - yes I checked the API documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview but it only details zoom level at 0:180, 1:90, 2:45 when I view via chrome or IE8 I get zoom level at 0:127, 1:90, 2:53 but can't see these values documented anywhere

Answer (score 5):

Currently, there is a table [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) relating zoom and FOV that says:

`0=>180  1=>90  2=>45 3=>22.5 4=>11.5`

You can convert from zoom to FOV in javascript like this:

`var fov = 180 / Math.pow(2,zoom);`

Comment: And from FOV to zoom: `var zoom = -(Math.log(fov/45)-2*Math.log(2))/Math.log(2)`

Answer (score 1):

the issue is with when the maps api supports the use of CANVAS with the specific browser

Maps API version 3.7 January 24, 2012 included Enabled Canvas Street View on IE 9, Opera and Safari/Windows

using maps api 3.6 that doesn't support canvas in maps ( except chrome browser ) you get the FOV as 0: 180, 1: 90, 2: 45, 3: 22.5, 4: 11:25

any streetview loaded within a maps supported canvas get FOV as 
0: 127, 1: 90, 2: 53, 3: 28, 4: 14

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the solution other than to use 90 degree FOV which is consistent at zoom 1 for all browsers that I have tested

Answer (score 0):

It is not direct answer to a question, but maybe it helps:

There is undocumented option of google.maps.StreetViewPanorama class named 'mode'. You will be able to force rendering mode, and FOV should be the same for eg. 'html5'

[Google Maps API custom Street View quality issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663724/google-maps-api-custom-street-view-quality-issue/23014605#23014605)

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be the first result on google, for anyone interested, you can use the formula

```
Math.atan(Math.pow(2, 1 - zoom)) * 360 / Math.PI
```

to get the zoom levels

```
0: 127, 1: 90, 2: 53, 3: 28, 4: 14
```

I couldn't find this anywhere in the documentation, but it fits the data perfectly and looks like the math for a cylindrical projection.