# Google Maps API custom Street View quality issue

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I created a Google Photo Sphere and I want to embed this on my page:

- Using iframe, everything works ok:

  http://fotomilo.pl/test_iframe.aspx — quality is ok.
- Using JavaScript API, there are problems:

  http://fotomilo.pl/test_js.html — quality is poor.

Quality issue:

[image: Example]

It look like tiles mismatch. Look at the image and panorama rendered with JavaScript.

Comment: "look at this image" There is no image :)

Comment: http://fotomilo.pl/lib/res/_SV_pano.png - I meant this image, but I was able to post only 2 links, this is the third.

Comment: Well I belive it just cannot be perfect with js+css - different browsers implement js and css differently and there always will be small differences/imperfections in behaviour. Note that on firefox there is no tiling mismatch, but images are warped.

Comment: I don't think so, I've tested panorama rendering  with GSV API on IE, FF and Chrome. I susspect there is a different kind of API for, let's say, professionals - look at the TourDash : https://live.tourdash.com/embed/530071b5d3e44a02a2debd7a4065e7df , I'm pretty sure they are using js API, because they placed custom markers on their tour- unfortunetally, code is obfuscated.

Comment: You're right, hard to say whats wrong, they are using older api version, but that shouldnt be an issue... D:

Comment: My IFRAME version is rendered with flash, but original photosphere uses HTML5 : https://www.google.com/maps/views/view/102317523714566000370/photo/8AhpovHXA2IAAAAGOvwr3w?gl=pl&heading=264&pitch=98&fovy=75 , but google code is also very messy :/

Answer (score 10):

I've been looking for solution quite long and I finally found..

...**undocumented option** of google.maps.StreetViewPanorama class named 'mode':

- 'html4': Street View tiles are rendered as HTML  tags without
  warping.
- 'html5': Street View tiles are rendered using Canvas 2D.
- 'webgl': Street View tiles are rendered using WebGL (aka Canvas 3D).

For example:

```
...

var map = new google.maps.Map( canvasElement, mapOptions );
var panorama = map.getStreetView();

var options = { mode : 'html4' };

panorama.setOptions( options );

...
```

Try it.

(found at [this tread](http://osdir.com/ml/google-maps-js-api-v3/2013-02/msg00015.html))

Comment: Yes it seems to work (at least on our configuration) but for how long ?