# Google Street View rendering fisheye like in Safari?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is there a way to get Safari to render street view correctly using **V3.23** of the google maps API? In google chrome it displays fine but not in Safari.

One solution I did find was to use the following code which uses google's new beta renderer for streetview, however it does not show the navigation chevrons on mobile, and on desktop (safari) they seem very buggy:

```
google.maps.streetViewViewer = 'photosphere';
```

More info [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6306) (last post)

**Google Chrome:**

[image]

**Safari 9.0.3**

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I noticed that setting zoom to 1 (rather than 0) fixed the "fisheye" effect I saw on streetview

Answer (score 2):

So I have discovered that there was an unpublished bit of code for the api which lets you change the mode. I used the 'webgl' mode and it seems to work, its not perfect but better than the other options.

...undocumented option of google.maps.StreetViewPanorama class named 'mode':

- 'html4': Street View tiles are rendered as HTML tags without warping.
- 'html5': Street View tiles are rendered using Canvas 2D.
- 'webgl': Street View tiles are rendered using WebGL (aka Canvas 3D).

---

```
var map = new google.maps.Map( canvasElement, mapOptions );
var panorama = map.getStreetView();

var options = { mode : 'webgl' };

panorama.setOptions( options );
```

Found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663724/google-maps-api-custom-street-view-quality-issue)

If there are any other solutions then let me know.