# Google Street View JS - FoV & FoV Event

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view, fieldofview

I am building an app that uses an image from the Google Street View API. I am needing to zoom in to the image.

I am using the event `pov_changed`, I track changes to the POV pitch and heading. To decide the zoom in the final image I need a FoV (Field of View) attribute.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=700x600&location=40.159172842909,-103.201315097248&heading=22.3118227257402&pitch=-1.42049583899625&key=<key>&fov=20
```

I have a setup like this...

```
  center = new google.maps.LatLng(address.latitude, address.longitude)

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: address.zoom
  })

  street = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('street'), {
    position: center,
    pov: {
      heading: address.pov_heading || 150,
      pitch: address.pov_pitch || 0.75
    }
  })
```

To get get the values to update a form I have some thing like... but I can't find how to get the Field of View attribute.

```
  street.addListener 'pov_changed', ->
    pitchField.html(street.getPov().pitch)
    headingField.html(street.getPov().heading)
    # console.log(street.getFov()) # is not a function
    # console.log(street.getFoV()) # is not a function
    # console.log(street.getFOV()) # is not a function
```

How can I find the Field of View to use in a link as above to zoom in to the image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794436/how-can-i-determine-the-field-of-view-a-street-view-panorama-map-is-using

Comment: @anatoly.sukhanov: how to get the FOV is the question, i only need to find the FOV

Answer (score 0):

You can't get FOV, it's not in the API 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference

As anatoly.sukhanov posted, you can find the way to calculate it in this question already asked on SO [how can I determine the Field of View a street view panorama map is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794436/how-can-i-determine-the-field-of-view-a-street-view-panorama-map-is-using)